# Making library for arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, library, keypad

I'm learning library making on arduino , I want to make a library that works with arrays a user sets, e.g:

User sets array of int,
when  a certain function is been called the library will check if some instance are true or not ann set the return function accordingly as the array.

Code example:

```
    //in project example


#include <Keyss.h>

int rows=4;
int cols=2;
int a=0;
int b=1;
int c=2;
int inp=3;
int keyss[4][2]={
{0,1},,
{2,3},
{4,5},
{6,7}
};

Key key((keyss),rows,cols,inp,a,b,c);

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
int keyprint=key.getkey();
Serial.println(key print);
}
void loop(){
}
```

And this will be the library files
Keys.h

```
#ifndef KEYSS_H
#define KEYSS_H
#include <Arduino.h>


class Key {

public:

Key(int (*keys)[4],int rows,int cols,int inp,int t1,int t2,int t3);
int getkey();
int waitforkey();

private:

int *_keys;
int _rows;
int _cols;
int _inp;
int _t1;
int _t2;
int _t3;

};



#endif
```

And
Keys.CPP

```
#include <Keyss.h>

//initialization

Key::Key(int (*keys)[4],int rows,int cols,int inp,int t1,int t2,int t3){

 _keys=keys[4];
 _rows=rows;
 _cols=cols;
 _inp=inp;
 _t1=t1;
 _t2=t2;
 _t3=t3;

 pinMode(_inp,INPUT);
 pinMode(_t1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(_t2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(_t3,OUTPUT);

}

//getkey()

int Key::getkey(){

int _a;
int _b;
int _i=0;
int _keymap=false;
int _val;
int _dt=500;
int _s1;
int _input;

for(_a=0;_a<_rows;_a++){

 for(_b=0;_b<_cols;_b++){

  _s1=_i;
  digitalWrite(_t1,(_s1>>0)&1);
  digitalWrite(_t2,(_s1>>1)&1);
  digitalWrite(_t3,(_s1>>2)&1);
  delayMicroseconds(_dt);

  _input=digitalRead(_inp);

  if(_input==true && _keymap==false){

   _val=_keys[_a*_cols+_b];
   _keymap=true;
}

  _i++;

}
}

if(_keymap==false){
   _val=-1;
}

return _val;

}



//waitforkey()

int Key::waitforkey(){

int _waitfor=getkey();

while(_waitfor<0){

_waitfor=getkey();

}

return _waitfor;

}
```

Where I have problem now is I don't know how to
use or assign an array in a library
I don't know how to use functions to refer to an array a user inputes, like here

```
int keyss[4][2]={
{0,1},
{2,3},
{4,5},
{6,7}
};
```

How do I use a function or inside the library to refer to the array a user sets?

Please how do I achieve that?

Its giving this error
[image: error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `keys` variable is a 2D array of `int`, i.e. it is an array of
arrays. In C++, when an array is assigned to a variable or passed as an
argument, it implicitly decays to a pointer to its first element.
Note, however, that the decay-to-pointer behavior is not recursive.
In this case you end up with a pointer to an array of three `int`.

Your code should work if you give the proper type to the `_keys` class
member and the `keys` constructor parameter:

```cpp
class Key {
public:
    Key(int (*keys)[3], int trig1, int trig2, int trig3, int inpin);
    int getkey();

private:
    int (*_keys)[3];  // pointer to array of 3 int.
    int _trig1;
    int _trig2;
    int _trig3;
    int _inpin;
    int _keye;
};
```

---

**Edit**: You have completely changed the question, to the point that my
answer may not be relevant anymore. In the previous version of the
question, it looked like you wanted to use a 3×3 2D array of numbers in
the class. In the current version, you are using an array of arbitrary
sizes represented as a flattened 1D array. These are quite different
approaches.

If you want to use a 2D array, the number of *columns* has to be a
compile-time constant. You have to declare the member variable as a
pointer-to-array like this:

```cpp
int (*_keys)[2];  // there are two columns, not four!
```

assign it like this:

```cpp
_keys = keys;  // do NOT subscript keys
```

and use it like this:

```cpp
_val = _keys[_a][_b];  // it is a 2D array
```

This approach cannot work if you do not know the number of columns
beforehand.

If you want to use a flattened (1D) array, then the parameter of the
constructor has to be a simple `int*`, and you have to give it the
address of the first element of the original 2D array:

```cpp
Key key(&keyss[0][0], rows, cols, inp, a, b, c);
```

The drawback of using a flattened array is that, in order to access the
elements, you have to perform explicit index calculations:

```cpp
_val = _keys[_a*_cols + _b];
```

Comment: I tried it but I don't know the correct way to do it

Comment: Thanks bro  I didn't understand it that much earlier and also I am   new to  programming, but now I have understand it more